# как вывести данные из массива в wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Вставляю этот код на страницу в WP

```
[insert_php]

$results = $wpdb2->get_result("SELECT FIELD1 FROM mytable Limit 10 ");

foreach($results as $key => $value){
 echo  $key $value ;
}

[/insert_php]
```

и после апдейта ничего не происходит, страница пустая.
при чем если get_result заменить на get_var, a foreach на простое echo одно значение на странице появляется.

До этого с php дел не имел.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Обратите внимание что у вас не хватает буквы s в методе запроса get_result**s**. Судя по коду вы создаете новый объект класса wpdb, проверьте корректно ли у вас он создан, пример:

   global $wpdb2;
   $wpdb2 = new wpdb( 'имя_юзера', 'пароль', 'название_БД', 'localhost' );
   $results = $wpdb2->get_results("SELECT * FROM table");

но лучше все же использовать уже существующий объект:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb2->get_results("SELECT * FROM table");
```

2. Затем в цикле у вас ошибка (если не опечатка) `echo  $key $value ;`

не хватает запятой или точки между переменными:`echo $key, ' ', $value;` 
или `еcho $key . ' ' . $value;`